# Why would a double.Parse calls success be affected by a Console.WriteLine or delay?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following class:

```
public class Point {

    public Point(string latitude, string longitude)
    {
        Longitude = double.Parse(longitude.ToString());
        Latitude = double.Parse(latitude.ToString());
    }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

I call it in a loop, with data read from an ASCII encoded file.

In the above form, for every iteration of the loop, when instantiating an instance of the class using

```
var p = new Geocode.Point(string1, string2);
```

the constructor fails with the following exception

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
    at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,
       NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
    at System.Double.Parse(String s)
```

However, if I alter the constructor for `Point` to the following:

```
public Point(string latitude, string longitude)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + latitude);
        Console.WriteLine("Longitude: " + longitude);
        Longitude = double.Parse(longitude.ToString());
        Latitude = double.Parse(latitude.ToString());
    }
```

and run the loop, the `double.Parse` succeeds.

Adding a `Thread.Sleep(100);` in place of the Console.WriteLine calls similarly ensures the loop runs without issue, so obviously there is a timing issue here, but why would there be in this particular instance, given that `string1` and `string2` are passed by value and not reference in both situations?

Comment: Can you print out the values of the two strings when you get the exception? (By the way, the ToString() is useless in presence of a variable already of type string)

Comment: @Steve printing out the variables in a catch block shows they are the correct values as intended to be passed in.  And I know about the ToString being worthless, their presence was merely part of my testing prior to asking here :)

Comment: Are you wait long enough to process all the data?

Comment: If you track down the value combination at which the program chokes, you could create a ~10 line program that reproduces the scenario (with those values hardcoded instead of read from a file). You might also want to check your culture settings (read the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` value).

Comment: Just post an exact string on which `double.Parse` fails, that is all what is needed here.

Comment: Can you show how you read the ASCII encoded file? Do you use any async methods?